# What does 的 mean in sentences like "我会死的"?

Tags: grammar

What does the 的 mean/indicate/do in sentences like "我会死的"?

I hear things like this in the Chinese movies I'm watching for listening practice.

I would say something like "我会死亡" or just "我会死".

Another example I just heard is: "爸爸不做饭的".

Comment: grammar topic:＂是。。。的＂ sentence (是 can be omitted, as can 的), 会...的 occurs esp. often, (search site for previous discussions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a particle like 呢 or 了 etc. Obviously 的 also has several other uses and it can sometimes be difficult to tell them apart especially if you have no context to the sentence.

The way it's used here is as a MODAL particle. Meaning that it alters the mood of the sentence. It makes the sentence feel like a a confident prediction.

Answer (score 1):

> *的 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/6/*
>
> *[dik1 & de5] [1] possessive; adjectival suffix [2] **final particle***

'的' in  "我会死的" is a final particle.

我会死 (plain statement)

我会死(的) (1.indicates phrase ends. 2. put emphasis on the phrase and/or adds affirming tone to it)

*The meaning of a final particle can change, depend on the context and tone of the voice*

*的 has other usage in different context, check the link in this post*

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/1f/js/7684.htm), definition 4:

> 4. 助词，用在句末，表示肯定的语气，常与“是”相应：这句话是很对～。